# MySQL Unhelpful SQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, forum

I have another error with my MySQL, Which is as follows:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I have experienced this error before by removing unnecessary quotes, however this doesn't appear to be the problem this time. All the times I saw the question asked on stack overflow too, the questions were either because of unnecessary quotes or were very unique to that code. If anyone can help me or point me towards a useful answer, I would appreciate that! :^]

Code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT(sect_id, sect_name, sect_desc)FROM sections WHERE sect_id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET["id"]);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(!$result)
{
echo 'The sections could not be displayed, please try again later.' . mysqli_error($con);
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the column names

Comment: `var_dump($sql);` (or `$result`) (or echo) - what do you get?

Comment: @juergend Tried that sadly, Didn't work

Comment: @Fred-ii- bool(false)

Comment: _Side note:_ You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not as secure as one would hope.

Comment: Dump `$_GET['id']` and check if it actually contains what you think it does?

Comment: It sounds like `$_GET["id"]` is not set or is empty at the point that you are inserting it into `$sql`. This results in your SQL query being `SELECT(sect_id, sect_name, sect_desc)FROM sections WHERE sect_id = ;` and would return the error you are seeing. Verify that `$_GET["id"]` contains something before executing the statement.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_GET["id"]);` produce and what should it be? as stated; sounds like your GET array is empty or it's a string.

Answer (score -1):

This error message isn't unhelpful. You just need to be accustomed with the way mysql reports its errors.

When the reported query part is empty, it means that the error occurred [*at the very end of the query*](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting#interpretation).

It means that `$_GET["id"]` is empty, producing incorrect SQL statement

```
SELECT(sect_id, sect_name, sect_desc)FROM sections WHERE sect_id =
```

to fix that, you should **ALWAYS** use **prepared statements**.

Beside syntax, prepared statement will fix the **sql injection** to which your query is essentially prone.

Besides, next error to appear is wrong syntax for the fields list, from which braces should be removed.